# How to prevent zooming of an object with a fixed position on the iPhone (and other mobile devices)

Tags: css, mobile

I have a web page with a menu fixed to the bottom of the page. When you zoom in on the page with the iPhone (and presumably other mobile devices), the menu also zooms but remains fixed to the bottom of the screen, which causes it to eat up all the screen real estate. Is there any way to keep this menu a fixed size regardless of zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could solve your problem: http://davidwalsh.name/zoom-mobile-browsers

Comment: This method prevents zoom on the entire page. Not just the menu element that was asked in the question.